# Is there a way to enable smart guides when moving a layer with your keyboard in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, guides

So I just started Photoshop and I'm using the pink lined smart guides to align all of my content.  The problem is, they're only active when I drag a layer with my mouse, which is hard to do because I have a trackpad.  Moving layers around with my keyboard allows me to be much more accurate, but smart guides seem to shut off when I do.  Any solution to this would help.

Comment: So, is there some reason you can't you have a trackpad, and a mouse?  If the trackpad is difficult to use for that purpose, then it's as good as useless.

Comment: Either you need to learn how to use your trackpad or you have to get a mouse

Comment: @BillyKerr a mouse wouldn't necessarily help. It's just easier to move layers pixel by pixel with the keyboard

Comment: @Manly I imagine it's difficult for anyone to move an object pixel-by-pixel using a trackpad.  My expertise with the trackpad is not of issue and shouldn't be addressed either

Comment: @EggMon - Ok, gonna add an answer now, which might help you.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have one layer selected (i.e. the layer you are moving), and have the Move Tool hover over another object on another layer, you can hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> while you use the arrow keys.  If you are on a Mac, presumably <kbd>Command</kbd> would do the same.

In this example, I am moving the pentagon with the arrow keys, while the move tool is over the triangle.

[image]

Comment: Cool! As far as I had been concerned this was not possible... Thanks for this Billy Kerr